# ARM GCC Compiling errors (Windows 7)

Tags: gcc, arm, cross-compiling, gnu

Here is my entered command and what it spits out: Unfortunately, google has not been of much help, but I have tried several things (from my extremely beginner knowledge) and I have not been able to solve it.

```
C:\Users\Z\workspace\TEST\src>gcc main.c
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.7 2013q1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none
-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-exit.o): In function `exit':

exit.c:(.text.exit+0x2c): undefined reference to `_exit'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.7 2013q1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none
-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':

sbrkr.c:(.text._sbrk_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.7 2013q1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none
-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-writer.o): In function `_write_r':

writer.c:(.text._write_r+0x20): undefined reference to `_write'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.7 2013q1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none
-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-closer.o): In function `_close_r':

closer.c:(.text._close_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_close'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.7 2013q1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none
-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): In function `_fstat_r':

fstatr.c:(.text._fstat_r+0x1c): undefined reference to `_fstat'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.7 2013q1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none
-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): In function `
_isatty_r':

isattyr.c:(.text._isatty_r+0x18): undefined reference to `_isatty'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.7 2013q1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none
-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): In function `_lseek_r':

lseekr.c:(.text._lseek_r+0x20): undefined reference to `_lseek'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/4.7 2013q1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none
-eabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib\libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): In function `_read_r':

readr.c:(.text._read_r+0x20): undefined reference to `_read'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

main.c contains the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    puts("!!!Hello World!!!"); /* prints !!!Hello World!!! */
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

`gcc -v` returns version info so path is right

Comment: Well, you have library issues.  It seems you are using a `newlib` compiler.  And you are programming for **Linux**, **Android**, an **iPhone**, or a **bare metal** or **free-standing** environment?  Your host is **Window 7** or this is a **Windows Phone**?  For `newlib`, there are a few minimal functions that must be implemented for the board.  Have you implemented these or was the compiler labeled as being for a *BeagleBoard*, *Raspberry Pi*, etc.  Where did you get the compiler from?  Please answer some of these question to help the next person who looks at your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing for ARM7 or ARM9 or ARM9 running linux?
You need different tool chains for each of these.

Seems like you are developing for ARM7 (looking at the compiler executable name), if not, then you might be using the wrong compiler.

The problem it seems is that you have not setup the compiler toolchain properly, it needs proper installation with proper paths set.

I have some instructions for setting arm YAGARTO (a particular distribution for arm-gcc) here:
(http://www.electronicsfaq.com/2012/11/blinky-and-printf-on-netduino-using.html)

I use [netduino](http://netduino.com/) board which has a ARM7 on it.